# \BindingResolutionException: Target class [0] does not exist

Tags: laravel

I developed backend for my flutter project,and i use laravel,
yesterday my laravel app work fine, but today i get this error,
yesterday, i created some controllers,i search for this problem, but not found anything,
i search and someone said that this error (Warning: A non-numeric value encountered) occur when you use `+` instead of `.` but i not use `+` anywhere

```
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\iShop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 917
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [0] does not exist. in file C:\xampp\htdocs\iShop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 875
```

This is my api:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DatabaseController;
use App\Http\Controllers\TestController;
use App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::post('/register',[AuthController::class,'register']);
Route::post('/login',[AuthController::class,'login']);
Route::post('/test',[TestController::class,'test']);
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });

    
    Route::middleware('scopes:createDatabase,downloadDatabase')->group(function(){
        Route::post('/saveDatabase',[DatabaseController::class,'saveDatabase']);

        Route::post('/download',[DatabaseController::class,'downloadDatabase']);
    });

    Route::post('confirm_staff_database',[DatabaseController::class,'confirmStaffDatabase'])->middleware('scopes:updateDatabase');
    
    Route::resource('/employee',EmployeeController::class)->middleware('scopes:selectEmployee,createEmployee,updateEmployee,deleteEmployee');
});
```

This is my DatabaseController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Database;
use Str;
use Response;

class DatabaseController extends Controller
{

    public function saveDatabase(Request $request){
        $path=getFile($request);
        $result=auth()->user()->databases->create([
            'database_path'=>$path
            ]);
        return $result;
    }

    private function getFile(Request $request){
        return $request->file('database')->store('public');
    }

    private function getLastDatabase(){
        $company=auth()->user()->company;
        $users=User::with('databases')->where([['company',$company],['role','user']])->get();
        $database_id=$users->map(function($item){
            return $item->databases->last();
        })->max()->id;
        return Database::find($database_id);
    }

    public function downloadDatabase(){
        $path=$this->getLastDatabase()->database_path;
        return Response::download(storage_path().'/app/public/'.$path);
    }

    public function confirmStaffDatabase(Request $request){
        $database=Database::where([['uploadable_type','App\Models\Employee'],['uploadable_id',$request->employee_id]])->last();
        if(!$database){
            return response()->json('این دیتابیس قبلا تایید شده است',404);
        }
        $result=$database->update([
                'uploadable_id',auth()->user()->id,
                'uploadable_type','App\Models\User'
            ]);
        if($result){
            return respone()->json('عملیات موفقانه انجام شد');
        }
        return response()->json('مشکلی رخ داده است',500);
    }
}
```

This is my EmployeeController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Employee;
use Validator;
class EmployeeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validate=Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name'=>'required|min:3|unique:users',
            ]);
        if($validate->fails()){
            return response()->json($validate->errors(),203);
        }
        $allData=$request->all();
        $allData['secret']=Str::random(8);
        $allData['password']=bcrypt($allData['secret']);
        $allData['role']='staff';
        $allData['device_mac']=$request->mac;
        $user=User::create($allData);
        $token=$user->createToken('api-staff',['createDatabase','downloadDatabase']);
        $res['name']=$user->name;
        $res['company']=$user->company;
        $res['secret']=$user->secret;
        return response()->json($res,200);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $employee=Employee::find($id);
        if(!$employee){
            return response()->json('کارمند وجود ندارد',404);
        }
        $result=$employee->update([
            'name'=>$request->name,
            'secret'=>$request->password,
            'password'=>bcrypt($request->password),
            'role'=>$request->role,
            ]);
        if($result){
            return response()->json('عملیات انجام شد');
        }
        return response()->json('عملیات انجام نشد',500);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $employee=Employee::find($id);
        if(!$employee){
            return response()->json('کارمند وجود ندارد',404);
        }

        $result=$employee->delete();
        if($result){
            return response()->json('عملیات انجام شد');
        }
        return response()->json('عملیات انجام نشد',500);
    }
}
```

This is my AuthController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Validator;
use Str;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request){
        $validate=Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name'=>'required|min:3|unique:users',
            ]);
        if($validate->fails()){
            return response()->json($validate->errors(),203);
        }
        $allData=$request->all();
        $allData['secret']=Str::random(8);
        $allData['password']=bcrypt($allData['secret']);
        $allData['role']='user';
        $allData['device_mac']=$request->mac;
        $user=User::create($allData);
        $token=$user->createToken('api-user',['downloadDatabase','createDatabase','updateDatabase','selectEmployee','createEmployee','updateEmployee','deleteEmployee']);
        $res['name']=$user->name;
        $res['company']=$user->company;
        $res['secret']=$user->secret;
        return response()->json($res,200);
    }

    public function login(Request $request){
        $validate=$request->validate([
            'name'=>'required|min:3',
            'password'=>'required|min:6',
            ]);
        if(auth()->attempt($validate)){
            $token=auth()->user()->createToken('api-user',['downloadDatabase','createDatabase','updateDatabase','selectEmployee','createEmployee','updateEmployee','deleteEmployee'])->accessToken;
            $res['name']=auth()->user()->name;
            $res['token']=$token;
            return response()->json($res,200);       
        }
        return response()->json('نام یا رمز اشتباه است',203);        
    }
}
```

This is my AuthServiceProvider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        Passport::routes();

        Passport::tokensCan([
            'downloadDatabase'=>'download Database',
            'createDatabase'=>'create Database',
            'updateDatabase'=>'update Database',
            'selectEmployee'=>'select Employee',
            'createEmployee'=>'create Employee',
            'updateEmployee'=>'update Employee',
            'deleteEmployee'=>'delete Employee',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show complete stack of error?

Comment: Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\iShop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 917
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [0] does not exist. in file C:\xampp\htdocs\iShop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 875

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\iShop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(754): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('0')

Comment: Laravel return complete trace of error. Check you log

Comment: all of logs can't comment

Comment: With limited error trace not possible to debug

Comment: You have to show us your full log, if you can't because it is huge, find on it any path that does not point to `\vendor` but to `\app`, and you will see what was your last line of code called before it went to core to resolve that petition.